# Binding scope doesn't change inside collectionview/listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an ObservableCollection of Stylist that I want to display in my view using a CollectionView

this is the code for collectionview

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Appointments.ViewModels" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:WallViewModel"
             x:Class="Appointments.Views.WallPage">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:WallViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <FlexLayout 
                JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"
                Margin="10, 20">

                <Entry 
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="search.."/>
                <Button 
                    Text="Filters"
                    Command="{Binding OpenFilterCommand}"
                    />
            </FlexLayout>

            <CollectionView 
                x:Name="StylistList"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Stylists}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The Stylist model inherits from a User model that has a public property "Name"

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

but if I run this code it will throw an error saying

"Binding: Propery "Name" not found on WallViewModel"

but if I change the that label to bind to

```
<Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
```

and while the app is running I change it back to

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

it will work fine and display all the names inside the collection

Comment: try removing `x:DataType="viewmodels:WallViewModel"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you set the code below into a User model, when you use `x:DataType="viewmodels:WallViewModel"` would thrown the error `Property "Name" not found on "App8.WallViewModel".`.

```
  public string Name { get; set; }
```

If you change the use the x:DataType, you nned to use the class which include the Name property.

For more details about the x:DataType, please check the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-
binding/compiled-bindings

As Jason said, remove the `x:DataType="viewmodels:WallViewModel"` would fix the this error.

After removing the `x:DataType="viewmodels:WallViewModel`, `<Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the iterated type inside the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:xxx">
...
</DataTemplate>
```